# Función se cicla cuando mando llamar la función por si misma

Tags: php, json, curl

Tengo una función que genera tokens de acceso y los retorna (conexion_dos()), pero resulta que el token caduca después de una hora. La función conexion_dos la mando llamar en la función insertLlamadas, para poder insertar necesitar de 2 parámetros (datos en formato json los cuales ya los estoy mandando bien y también necesita del token), pero como les comento el token dura solo una hora y caduca entonces tendría que generar uno nuevo.

Ya comprobé el error que manda cuando el código ya caduco el cual es el error 1030 y tengo un if para cachar ese error el cual esta entrando bien, entonces genero un nuevo token pero cuando mando llamar así misma la función () para que haga el insert el proceso se cicla y no entiendo porque.

Pueden ayudarme a saber porque se cicla el proceso cuando genero el token nuevo y mando llamar la función por si misma o de que otra forma puedo hacer el proceso que intento hacer.

Les comparto mi intento de código.

> El error que me está mandando cuando no es válido o ya caducó.

***stdClass Object ( [code] => 1030 [description] => Authorization Failure. The access token is either invalid or has expired. Please check your Zoho Account for more information. )***

Función que inserta los datos (la función recibe como parámetros el json de datos y el token).

```
$acceso_final_global = "1000.39022ce49e58bf4f67d0e2f3db83325c.62cd7d6bf688cd5a4e45a7c61b52a2df";

function insertLlamadas($data_json){
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://creator.zoho.com/api/v2/nombre/zoho-cdr/form/insert_final",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data_json),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken ".$acceso_final_global,
      "Content-Type: text/plain",
      "Cookie: 442b5845d7=f0ca98fc689b02462286b17d3e437fd5; zccpn=d38dce44-b631-4b67-9159-f870c828636a; _zcsr_tmp=d38dce44-b631-4b67-9159-f870c828636a; ZCNEWLIVEUI=true"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);

  if ($response === false){
      print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
  }

  $response = json_decode($response);
    if ($response->code == 1030) {
      // Aqui estoy obteniedo un token nuevo y si lo esta generando bien
      $acceso_final_global = conexion_dos();
      // Aqui es cuando mando llamar la funcion por si misma y el proceso se cicla
      // Saben por que? 
      // De que otra forma lo puedo hacer?
      insertLlamadas($data_json);
  }

  curl_close($curl);
}
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente lunes.

Comment: Intenta colocando `global $acceso_final_global;` como **primera línea** en tu función `insertLlamadas( )`. Si funciona te lo explico.

Comment: global $acceso_final_global; lo coloco dentro de la función?? o global como esta ??

Comment: Dentro de la función. A ser posible, como primera línea.

Comment: se sigue ciclando, no entiendo por que si veo que todo es correcto :c

Comment: Pues no tienes muchas opciones. O tu `conexion_dos( )` no está haciendo lo que debe, o el código de retorno `1030` sirve para mas cosas aparte de indicar un error.

Comment: pero verdad que mi código es correcto como lo estoy estructurando

Comment: Tal y como lo estás estructurando y ya te habrás dado cuenta, corres el riesgo de entrar en bucle. Deberías usar alguna clase de contador de reintentos.

Comment: No está bien estructurado, porque la primera vez que lo ejecutas no existe la variable `$acceso_final_global` dentro de la función y, al menos en esa primera llamada, siempre vas a obtener error.

Comment: Estás usando Zoho por lo que veo, ¿dicho CRM no tiene sus propios métodos para refrescar un token? [Aquí](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/php-sdk/initialize.html) parece explicarse algo al respecto.